# Wordpress remove shortcode from content

Tags: wordpress, function, filter, shortcode

Is it possible to remove the gallery shortcode from the content before when `the_content()` is executed? I searched codex and found `remove_shortcode( $tag )` but they show no examples.

I tried adding to functions

```
function remove_gallery($content) {
    $content .= remove_shortcode('[gallery]');
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_gallery', 6);
```

It doesnt work..

**Update:**

I was able to unregister the shortcode using the code below, but it also removes the content

```
function remove_gallery($content) {
    return remove_shortcode('gallery', $content);
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_gallery', 6);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange. remove_shortcode ([codex link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_shortcode)) doesn't take a second argument.

You're returning either the true or false return of the remove_shortcode function, not the content with the shortcode removed.

Try either something like this in that second version of your function up there:

```
remove_shortcode('gallery');
return $content;
```

Or just put

```
 remove_shortcode('gallery');
```

In your functions.php file. The previous poster suggested including the [ ]'s, which I guess is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't returning the content. `strip_shortcodes()` would have been optimal if you could specify which shortcode to remove.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a relative old question, but the strip_shortcodes function does work!

```
global $post;
echo strip_shortcodes($post->post_content);
```

Easiest way if you ask me..

Comment: But keep in mind that `strip_shortcodes()` will remove *all* shortcodes, not just the 'gallery' shortcodes. The question concerns only the 'gallery' shortcodes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use sub string replacement like this:

```
function remove_gallery($content) {
    return str_replace('[gallery]', '', $content);
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_gallery', 6);
```

Bear in mind, this method does not come with good performance.

**update**: You can unregister the shotcode in function.php by adding code:

```
remove_shortcode('[gallery]');
```

Comment: Thank you! `str_replace` method works unfortunately unregistering the shortcode doesn't.

Comment: I was able to unregister using filter with an issue. Please see update above

Comment: I think what you did is not correct. to remove the short code, just add this code in the function.php: remove_shortcode('[gallery]');

Answer (score 2):

An old question, but after some digging and a combination of answers this worked for me:

```
<?php $content = get_the_content();

echo strip_shortcodes($content);?>
```

I was only inserting galleries, which I wanted to remove and display separately. Obviously if you want to remove a specific shortcode this might not be the solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but just in case someone is looking for a way to selectively remove a single shortcode or list of shortcodes from post content (or whatever string you've got) in WordPress, ex, you don't want to use strip_shortcodes to remove ALL shortcodes, you just want to remove the [abc id='blah'] shortcode or something:

```
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex( [ 'abc', 'shortcode2' ] );
$content = preg_replace_callback( "/$pattern/", 'strip_shortcode_tag', $content );
```

In this case $content is the string containing the short codes, and you can list one or more shortcode names in the array (replacing 'abc', 'shortcode2'). This still works even if the shortcode(s) you want to remove are not registered, for example if a former plugin used [pluginshortcode] you can remove those.