# strip_shortcodes doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, function

i'm a beginner in Wordpress and i'm trying to **remove all shortcodes from a post content** from a database. I found the function created for wordpress named "strip_shortcodes()" but i don't really know how to use it. I looked on internet and i still don't know where is my error...

There is the code :

```
$all_pages = $wpdb->get_results (
    "SELECT * FROM " . $post_table . " WHERE post_type = 'page' "
);

foreach ($all_pages as $page) {
    echo '<h1>' . $page->post_title . '</h1>';
    $content = $page->post_content;
    echo strip_shortcodes($content) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Result :**

> [spacer size="5"] [tabs style="1"] [tab title="Définition"] [heading
>   border="#cf3549" color="#444444" style="1"]Qu'est-ce qu'un hébergement
>   web ? [/heading] Il s'agit en fait de la location mensuelle (ou annuelle)
>   d'un serveur, en d'autres termes la location d'une machine ressemblant
>   vaguement à un PC dépouillé de son écran et sans système
>   d'exploitation traditionnel comme Windows ou Mac. Les systèmes
>   d'exploitation des serveurs sont généralement des logiciels libres
>   comme Linux, nginx ou des logiciels payants comme Windows server. Le
>   serveur web n'est que la partie matérielle (hardware), qu'il faut
>   coupler à un système d'exploitation correspondant à ses compétences,
>   c'est la partie logicielle (software).

**Excepted result:**

> Qu'est-ce qu'un hébergement web ? Il s'agit en fait de la location
>   mensuelle (ou annuelle) d'un serveur, en d'autres termes la location
>   d'une machine ressemblant vaguement à un PC dépouillé de son écran et
>   sans système d'exploitation traditionnel comme Windows ou Mac. Les
>   systèmes d'exploitation des serveurs sont généralement des logiciels
>   libres comme Linux, nginx ou des logiciels payants comme Windows
>   server. Le serveur web n'est que la partie matérielle (hardware),
>   qu'il faut coupler à un système d'exploitation correspondant à ses
>   compétences, c'est la partie logicielle (software).

Can someone tell me what is the problem please ?

Comment: what is it displaying and whats the expected output

Comment: Never mind, i edited it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
            $content = preg_replace('#\[[^\]]+\]#', '',$page->post_content);
            echo apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

try this

Comment: This works perfectly, whereas I couldn’t get the strip_shortcodes function to, um, strip shortcodes in my meta description generator in functions.php.

Answer (score 2):

**When viewing posts 'home' page, strip all shortcodes, but on other pages, such as single.php, do not strip the shortcodes.**

```
function remove_shortcode_from_index( $content ) {
  if ( is_home() ) {
    $content = strip_shortcodes( $content );
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_shortcode_from_index' );
```

Click here for more details : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/strip_shortcodes/

try this remove_shortcode() function may be its helpful.

[Wordpress remove shortcode from content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547525/wordpress-remove-shortcode-from-content)

Comment: thanks for your answer, and there is no way to remove shortcodes from a content which isn't in post home page ?

Comment: @Exprator give you right answer. and I thing there is a good way.

Comment: WC @CédricCosson.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good but you are missing saving it in the database. What is the output of the echo? 
I would do it like this (untested):

```
    $all_pages = $wpdb->get_results (
        "SELECT * FROM " . $post_table . " WHERE post_type = 'page' "
    );

    foreach ($all_pages as $key => $page) {
        $all_pages[$key]->post_content = strip_shortcodes($page->post_content);
        // Save the content to the database
        wp_update_post($all_pages[$key]);
    }
```